# How to alter functions without modifying themes core files

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to alter my theme's core files.  I am using child theme and I want to alter my core files functions from my `functions.php`.

This is a core file function:

```
// main blog drag and drop options
function cyberchimps_selected_elements() {
$options = array(
    'boxes_lite'     => __( 'Boxes Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
    "portfolio_lite" => __( 'Portfolio Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
    "blog_post_page" => __( 'Post Page', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
    "slider_lite"    => __( 'Slider Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' )
);

return $options;
}

add_filter( 'cyberchimps_elements_draganddrop_options', 'cyberchimps_selected_elements' );
```

Now, I just want to add one line in this code that is:

```
"box_lite" => __( 'box', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
```

And this one:

```
require_once( $directory_path . '/elements/boxes2.php' );
```

Anyone to help me in this?

Comment: Create you own function that calls `cyberchimps_selected_elements()` and adds those lines?

Answer (score 1):

There's an awesome WordPress function called [remove_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter). You could use it to remove the above function, and then re-add you modified version in your child theme's **functions.php**. Something like:

```
remove_filter( 'cyberchimps_elements_draganddrop_options', 'cyberchimps_selected_elements' );
add_filter( 'cyberchimps_elements_draganddrop_options', 'cyberchimps_selected_elements_child' );

// main blog drag and drop options
function cyberchimps_selected_elements_child() {
    $options = array(
        "box_lite" => __( 'box', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
        "portfolio_lite" => __( 'Portfolio Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
        "blog_post_page" => __( 'Post Page', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
        "slider_lite"    => __( 'Slider Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' )
    );

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: thanks. i have similar condition of 'add_action' should i make it 'remove_action' also?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply one parameter variable as per the below given code, It will surely work just you have to make sure that wherever you want to retrieve altered array of option you have to pass parameter value "false". The function call is also written below the code.. good luck with that...

```
// main blog drag and drop options
function cyberchimps_selected_elements($default=true) {
  if($default){
    $options = array(
      "boxes_lite"     => __( 'Boxes Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "portfolio_lite" => __( 'Portfolio Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "blog_post_page" => __( 'Post Page', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "slider_lite"    => __( 'Slider Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' )
    );
  } else {
    $options = array(
      "boxes_lite"     => __( 'Boxes Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "portfolio_lite" => __( 'Portfolio Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "blog_post_page" => __( 'Post Page', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "slider_lite"    => __( 'Slider Lite', 'cyberchimps_elements' ),
      "box_lite"       => __( 'box', 'cyberchimps_elements' )
    );
  }
return $options;
}
```

function call sample:

```
//function call
cyberchimps_selected_elements(false);
```